# Terraform Cognito User Pool as an identity provider in the app client

Tags: oauth, terraform, amazon-cognito

I am using terraform to create AWS Cognito User Pool.
As `supported_identity_providers` for the user pool client, I am able to add OIDC identity provider. But I also need to add Cognito User Pool as an additional identity provider.

How do i add both of them?

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "client"
  generate_secret     = true
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id
  supported_identity_providers = ["MySSO"] //how do I add Cognito User Pool as an identity provider here on top of "MySSO"??
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  allowed_oauth_flows = ["code"]
  allowed_oauth_scopes = ["email", "openid", "profile"]
  callback_urls = ["https://my_callback_url.com”]
  logout_urls = ["https://my_callback_url.com”]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPoolClient.html#CognitoUserPools-CreateUserPoolClient-request-SupportedIdentityProviders) says that you can use COGNITO in all uppercase, which worked for me:

```
supported_identity_providers = ["MySSO", "COGNITO"]
```